# Problem when I try to convert a data.frame string with date from "1996-04-22" => to "1996-04" in R (using as.Date and format functions )

Tags: r, database, date, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a data frame with a some Dates, I have to convert a format `"1996-04-22"` to `"1996-04"` in R. 
I have the good conversion but not in data type Date and when I tried to convert this to data type Date, I get "NA" everywhere.

//meteo is my date frame and date is where the dates are stocked

What I do :

```
meteo$date = format(meteo$date, "%Y-%m") 
meteo$date = as.Date(meteo$date, format = "%Y-%m")
```

Comment: Date objects need to have days. If you're only trying to format it as text, look at `format`

Comment: The `yearmon` class in the zoo package can represent dates having only year and month.

Answer (score 1):

use zoo library's function yearmon to get year and month. Date needs day also.

```
    library(zoo)
    format(as.yearmon(substring(toString(MY_DATE_VARIABLE), 1, 7 )), "%Y-%m")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
Unfortunately It worked to get the Date in year and month but it appears to be a "chr" data type..

Comment: I think the date needs the day in it, one solution is change the day to the first of the month and then keep the column as date type